# PHP syntax error although everything is correct?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im not sure why am I getting this syntax error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/test/db.php on line 13
```

The code seems fine to me... Can anyone give me a few tips? :)

```
$server = 'host';
$username   = 'username';
$password   = 'password';
$database   = 'database';

if(!mysql_connect($server, $username,  $password))
{
    exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
}

if(!mysql_select_db($database)
{
    exit('Error: could not select the database');
}
```

Comment: 2nd `if` is missing a `)`. It has 1 for `mysql_select_db()`, but needs another for `if ()`.

Comment: Clearly everything is not correct, otherwise there wouldn't be an error :p

Comment: The syntax error tells you what is wrong. The `{` was *unexpected*. When something is unexpected it means that something is wrong *before* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is missing a close parenthesis

```
if(!mysql_select_db($database) )
                               ^---Missing
{
exit('Error: could not select the database');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!mysql_select_db($database))
```

you missed a )

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)` (closing bracket) in this line:

```
if(!mysql_select_db($database))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a closing bracket in your second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing `)` in your second if statement:

```
if(!mysql_select_db($database) <<<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parenthesis:

```
if(!mysql_select_db($database))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case no one else told you. You missed a ) on the second if statement. That is a ")" or otherwise known as a closing parentheses.

Comment: 6 people told them before  you... in case you did not notice.

Comment: The more the merrier.

Comment: In this case, not really.

Comment: Yes, that rule always applies.